# How to convert rows into columns using PIVOT in SqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
Dimension   Meaning
---------   -------
Browser     IE9
Browser     IE10
Module      Ticket
Module      Board
OS          Windows
OS          Ios
OS          Linux
```

And I want something like all possible combinations:

```
Browser     Module     OS
-------     ------     ------
IE9         Ticket     Windows
IE9         Ticket     Ios
IE9         Ticket     Linux
IE10        Board      Windows
IE10        Board      Ios
IE10        Board      Linux
```

And so on... The source table wont grow much so no fancy performance needed is here and I don't mind to hard code the columns

I am currently using this query but I only get one row:

```
SELECT [Browser],[Module],[Os] FROM 
         (
            SELECT Meaning, Dimension 
            FROM [Mits].[dbo].[ToolHintValues]
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            MAX(Meaning)
            FOR Dimension IN ([Browser],[Module],[Os])
         ) p
```

Any help on how can I get all the combinations?
Thanks in advance

Update: 
This is the dynamic sql version still returning one row:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Dimension) 
                from [dbo].[ToolHintValues]
                group by Dimension
                order by Dimension
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' FROM 
         (
            SELECT Meaning, Dimension 
            FROM [dbo].[ToolHintValues]
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            MAX(Meaning)
            FOR Dimension IN (' + @cols + N')
         ) p '
SELECT @query
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, there are 12 combinations.  Why do you only list six?

Comment: Yes 12 combinations, I just didn't want to write all of them, that's why I wrote "all possible combinations"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what the dimensions are, you can use `cross join`:

```
select b.meaning as browser, m.meaning as module, o.meaning as os
from (select distinct meaning from thistable where dimension = 'browser'
     ) b cross join
     (select distinct meaning from thistable where dimension = 'module'
     ) m cross join
     (select distinct meaning from thistable where dimension = 'os'
     ) o;
```

If you don't know all the dimensions, then you will have to do something more complicated with dynamic SQL.  A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns; to have a variable number, you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: #Mr.Linoff can you please explain brief how to use by dynamic queries

Comment: Just added my dynamic sql but still getting one row only.

Comment: @AlexMetalex . . . Are you saying that the above query returns only one row?  Pivot is not the right approach to get all combinations.  `cross join` is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes right, a cross join is the way to go. Any chance to make it work with a dyamic SQL ? ;)